# Tensorflow bucketing: Pad with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Given the following code:

```py
def elements_gen():
    sequence = [
        [[11, 22], [22, 22], [33, 22]],
        [[33, 22], [44, 22], [55, 22], [66, 22], [77, 22]],
        [[11, 22], [22, 22]],
        [[88, 22], [99, 22], [11, 22], [22, 22]],
    ]

    label = [1, 2, 1, 2]
    for x, y in zip(sequence, label):
        yield (x, y)


def element_length_fn(x, y):
    return tf.shape(x)[0]


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator=elements_gen,
    output_shapes=([None, 2], []),
    output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32),
)

dataset = dataset.apply(
    tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(
        element_length_func=element_length_fn,
        bucket_batch_sizes=[2, 2, 2],
        bucket_boundaries=[0, 5],
        padding_values=[0, 0],
    )
)

batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(4):
        print("Get_next:")
        print(sess.run(batch))
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a sequence. Input has type: <class 'list'>.`

What I want to achieve is pad the sequences with the following element `[0, 0]`.

Please let me know if the question seems confusing so I can include more info or express myself in a more clear way.

Comment: The error is in `bucket_by_sequence_length`, I suppose?

Comment: Yes it is. If I comment out that part of the code it works.

Comment: According to the documentation, padding with `0` is the default... In any case, have you tried using tuples (`(0, 0)`) instead of lists (`[0, 0]`)? I have seen some cases the API required you to use one and not the other (although it's uncommon).

Comment: @jdehesa no I haven't. But I don't quite understand what you mean by "using tuples instead of lists".

Comment: I mean try passing `padding_values=(0, 0)` (and maybe the other parameters as tuples too) instead of `padding_values=[0, 0]`. I know it sounds silly but I remember at least one case where that made the difference between working and failing.

Comment: @jdehesa I just tried that and it didn't work. I assume that I should play around with the argument `padded_shapes`. I've seen other issues where it was solved that way. But I am not able to figure how to use it.

Comment: @jdehesa wait a second. It did work actually but I am getting another error. Once I figure it out I will post the solution.

Comment: @jdehesa Ok. The other issue was that the for loop range was 4 and there were 2 batches. But your recommendation was correct. Can you post the initial comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach by @jdehesa works for what I needed and results in the following code:

```
def elements_gen():
    sequence = [
        [[11, 22], [22, 22], [33, 22]],
        [[33, 22], [44, 22], [55, 22], [66, 22], [77, 22]],
        [[11, 22], [22, 22]],
        [[88, 22], [99, 22], [11, 22], [22, 22]],
    ]

    label = [1, 2, 1, 2]
    for x, y in zip(sequence, label):
        yield (x, y)


def element_length_fn(x, y):
    return tf.shape(x)[0]


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator=elements_gen, output_shapes=([None, 2], []), output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32)
)

dataset = dataset.apply(
    tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length(
        element_length_func=element_length_fn,
        bucket_batch_sizes=[2, 2, 2],
        bucket_boundaries=[0, 5],
        padding_values=(0,0),
    )
)

batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(2):
        print("Get_next:")
        print(sess.run(batch))
```